# Is loading a link through a PHP page as opposed to directly from HTML signficantly slower when dealing with large traffic?

Tags: php, html

As opposed to changing 100 or so link on the index page, I want to load the link from a .php page like the following:

link.php would have:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mywebsite.com">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So instead of having a link directly in index.php, I would load everything from link.php

I'm worried though that because I'm dealing with a lot of traffic (10,000-50,000 clicks/day) It might cause significant slowness as opposed to having the direct links on my index page.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What steps would the end user be taking to interact with this script?

Comment: Where's the PHP in this? It looks like it's simply an html page with a redirect

Comment: Redirection should be implemented using an appropriate HTTP status code. Meta refresh is a no-go and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: PHP is certainly performant enough to handle the volume you're looking for, but you haven't provided enough information to understand what you're trying to accomplish, and the code snippet you've provided isn't something you would ever want to use in practice, there are at least 2 better ways to do it (as ZombieHunter indicated, you'll want to use an HTTP redirect, and there are multiple ways to accomplish this). What it seems like you're trying to do is learn just enough PHP to do some templating, which is fine.  Go learn some PHP, the first stuff you'll learn is what you're looking for.

Comment: The code I provided is in a php file (Link.php) and it is called inside the index.php file using <a href="link.php"> </a>

Comment: What does using `link.php` actually accomplish for you?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Jason, Link.php is simply where I insert the link I want to re-direct to. like in the HTML above.

my index.php, has the same link going across it about 100 times and I want to find a way to change the link that doesn't involve changing it by just find/replace (which could leave room for error)

so I thought that if I could just make one php file that if you change the link to, it will change all the links on index.php

Comment: @ZombieHunter Why is meta-refresh a no-go?

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing if all you do is refresh the current page, hints the `http-equiv="refresh"`. You however are using the refresh like a redirect. This does not allow the server to send the appropriate headers/codes such as ***301 Moved Permanently*** or ***307 Temporary Redirect***, etc. You should set these statuses and codes in the PHP file and then use the location header (`header('Location: ...url...');`) to redirect the user properly.

Comment: @Hussien_TooCoo: Take a look at these pages: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh and http://www.hostelmanagement.com/blog/meta-refresh-redirects-458.html

Comment: Ah, that finally makes more sense.  Alexis has your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a way for the repeated links in `index.php` to be generated automatically from a single definition, right? You can do that without involving a second file, or any redirects:

index.php:

```
<html>
<?php $mylink = '<a href="http://example.com">'; ?>
... 

<body>
Boy, I really like <?php print $mylink; ?>this</a> link. Everyone should 
visit it, just <?php print $mylink; ?>click here</a>. Etc.

</body>
</html>
```

Better yet: Define a function that generates the complete link for you:

```
<?php
function mylink($text)
{
   print '<a href="http://example.com">'.$text.'</a>';
}
?>
<html>
....

Take a look at <?php mylink("this link!"); ?>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just define the URL and include it as the value for the href throughout the document.  Let PHP be PHP, let HTML be HTML.

Comment: Fair enough. I just find this more readable, compared to embedding php brackets inside an `href` value: `<a href="<?php print $mylink;?>">this link</a>`